# My painting code consumes too much memory ( rephrased for better clarity )

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

### **INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:**

***FORMER TITTLE OF THE QUESTION:***

***Window produces flicker-like ( slow repainting-like ) effect when resized***

I have a complex painting to implement in my main window’s `WM_PAINT` handler.
I have submitted a picture bellow.

[image]

Logo’s marked with 1 and 2, are drawn using `GDI+`. Logo marked as 1, is `metafile`, and logo marked with 2 is `PNG`.

If I leave out drawing of the second logo, my window doesn’t flicker, yet if I add the drawing of the second logo in my `WM_PAINT`, the following effect, illustrated with the picture below, occurs ( this is just a sketch made in Paint, but hopefully it will clear things up ):

[image]

It seems as if the repainting is slow.

*IMPORTANT NOTE: This effect happens on child windows, the background is painted properly.*

Just in case it matters, the information about child windows:

All 5 child windows are static controls.

Static controls with blue gradient are painted with double buffering, using `GDI`, in `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.

Orange static control is `subclassed`, and is `ownerdrawn`.

*IMPORTANT NOTE: I must say that this is my first time using `GDI+`.*

In my `WM_PAINT` handler, I have made compatible memory DC, required for double buffering, like this:

```
   HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps), hdcMemImg, MemDC;
   MemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // back buffer.
```

Compatible bitmap has dimensions of main window’s client area.

As I’ve said, everything seems to work fine, since I use `GDI` and double buffering to paint/draw.

When I need to paint the logo’s marked with 1 and 2, I do it with this code:

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        Image image(L".\\resources\\BG.emf"), image1(L".\\resources\\RGF.png");
        switch(msg)
        {
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
           return (LRESULT)1;
        case WM_PAINT:
           {
              PAINTSTRUCT ps;
              HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps), hdcMemImg, MemDC;
              MemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // back buffer.
              // CreateCompatibleBitmap and other usual stuff
              /******************** left logo *******************/
              Graphics graphics( MemDC );
              //============= aspect ratio ================//
              UINT o_height = image.GetHeight(),
                   o_width =  image.GetWidth();
              INT n_width = 80;
              INT n_height = 100;
              double ratio = ( (double)o_width ) / ( (double)o_height );
              if (o_width > o_height)
              {
                  // Resize down by width
                  n_height = static_cast<UINT>( ( (double)n_width ) / ratio );
              }
              else
                  n_width = static_cast<UINT>(n_height * ratio);
              //========== ensure high graphic quality ======================//
              graphics.SetSmoothingMode( SmoothingModeHighQuality );
              graphics.SetInterpolationMode( InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic );
              graphics.DrawImage( &image, r.left + 5, r.top + 10, n_width, n_height );
              /******************** right logo *******************/
              Graphics graphics1( MemDC );
              //============= aspect ratio ================//
              o_height = image1.GetHeight(), 
              o_width = image1.GetWidth();
              n_width = 90;
              n_height = 100;
              ratio = ( (double)o_width ) / ( (double)o_height );
              if (o_width > o_height)
              {
                  // Resize down by width
                  n_height = static_cast<UINT>( ( (double)n_width ) / ratio );
              }
              else
                 n_width = static_cast<UINT>(n_height * ratio);
              //=========== ensure high graphic quality ============//
              graphics1.SetSmoothingMode( SmoothingModeHighQuality );
              graphics1.SetInterpolationMode( InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic );
              graphics1.DrawImage( &image1, r.right - r.left - 90, r.top + 10, n_width, n_height );
              // Then do BitBlt of MeDC to hdc, and clean it up
```

If additional code snippets are required, ask and I will edit my post, but for now, they are omitted to keep the post short and concise.

I work on Windows XP, using MS Visual Studio C++ and pure Win32 API.

My CPU is single core ( 2,67 GHz ), and I have 768 MB of RAM.

***IMPORTANT UPDATE:***

When I turn on `Task Manager`, I can see that the memory consumption of my application sky rockets.

It never drops, it always grows, especially when I resize the window.

Detailed description of my efforts to solve this can be found bellow.

I have decided to take the advice of the more experienced and better developers, and will provide link to the demo project.

**One note:** since Express edition of VS *has no resource editor*, resource file and resource header were created using `ResEdit` from here http://www.resedit.net/.

Here is the link to the demo project ( all the necessary comments and explanations are in the projects comments ):http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1382012579.

### **MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE PROBLEM:**

Browsing through the Internet, SO archive, CodeProject, and CodeGuru, I was unable to see the problem-it seems ( and I believe too ), that the principles of double buffering in `GDI+` and `GDI` are the same.

***IMPORTANT UPDATE:***

I have downloaded `VLD` from http://vld.codeplex.com/, followed their instructions, but `VLD` didn't detect any memory leaks.

Also, I have made a copy of the project and have deleted static controls, leaving only the window's background to ease my debugging.

Memory consumption described above still happens.

It seems to stop only if I don't draw logos.

### **QUESTION:**

Since this is my first time using `GDI+`, is there something that I’m missing, in view of releasing/deleting some `GDI+` object or something similar ( all the `GDI+` code for drawing in `WM_PAINT` is submitted )?

Again, I believe that my other painting code works well, but I will post it if required.

***UPDATE:***

*Regarding the updates provided above, what should I do to fix the problem of excessive memory consumption described above?*

*Can someone review small demo project provided above, and try to give me useful advice?*

Thank you.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved with great detailed explanations in this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/666738/Window-produces-flicker-like-slow-repainting-like

In case that link becomes dead, this is what I had to do:

1. Resize my left logo to proper dimensions;
2. Remove some memory leaks that I have missed;
3. Make `Image` objects global;

The 3rd action is what matters the most, since I load huge images repeatedly each time main window's procedure is called, which eventually completely consumes up memory.

Hope that this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Yo don't need to make it global; adding it as a class member could work as well. The important part is that you should save as much work from paint call to paint call. You could even consider saving the entire compatibleDC with the logo already rendered, and just testing if it's still compatible (because the window could have been dragged to another monitor)

Comment: @MSalters Thank you for such a useful comment.I have got similar suggestion from the site original answer came from.Since I am inexperienced developer, I couldn't come up with a proper implementation.I will create new question which will have a purpose to help me to optimize my painting code as much as possible.Thanks again.Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use more than one Graphics objects of GDI+.
Also be arware that the the deconstruction of this Graphics objects run after you copied the Bitmap back to the real DC. Thios also might cause side effects.

Place all use of the Graphics objects in own blocks so that the deconstruction occurs before you are copying the mem DC back to the paint DC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will implement your solution tomorrow, since I am currently in a mess.I will report my success as soon as possible. Regards.

Comment: I have modified my code per your instructions, but the effect persists. This  forces me to conclude that the problem might lie in painting of the static controls. Since the code is lengthy, I will post a project with painting code only, and will edit my question with link to it. Hopefully it will help. Thank you again. Regards.